# WordPress Loop Post Types as List und inset sub-posts in <ul><li> -> <ul>

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I'm stuck a little. I need to output a List of CPTypes with custom links. Everything is working so far. But I can't get the Subpages to be in a sub-list.

This is my code:

```
<? php
function theme_name_book_show_children($post) {
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=dokumentation', 'posts_per_page=>-1', 'post_parent=>$post_parent' );

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    $my_query->the_post();

echo '<li class="page_item ps2id"><a href="#' . get_the_id() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';

endwhile;
}
```

Any solitions for this? As far as I know list pages is only giving the permalink. But since it is a huge One-Pager i need to have it linked to the #ID.

Thank you for reading!

Mike

Comment: if the WP_Query is working that way? because an argument shall be an array()

Comment: yes - working flawless

Comment: Got this code now:

function theme_name_book_show_children($post_parent) {
$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=>'dokumentation', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'post_parent' => $post_parent ) );

if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
$my_query->the_post();

echo '<li class="page_item ps2id"><a href="#' . $my_query->post->ID . '">' . $my_query->post->post_title . '</a></li>';

endwhile;
} else {
// no results, maybe echo a message
}
wp_reset_postdata();
} 

only the hierarchy is missing… Any idea?

Comment: sorry, i can't understand what exactly is not working? don't you gen an <li> echoed? doesn't wp loops through the query? does the query return nothing?

Comment: $my_query->post->ID this is completely incorrect

Comment: shall be $post->ID and global $post variable has to be defined. I will write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function theme_name_book_show_children($parent_id) {
  global $post;
  $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'=>'dokumentation', 
    'posts_per_page'=>-1, 
    'post_parent'=>$parent_id 
  ) );

  while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();    
    echo '<li class="page_item ps2id"><a href="#' . $post->ID . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';    
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! Works.